# Is /usr/bin/python3 provided with macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, python

Is `/usr/bin/python3` provided with macOS Catalina?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Kinda. A clean installation of Catalina includes a `/usr/bin/python3` binary, but it's a stub for installing the command line developer tools, which includes Python 3.

[image]

If/when the command line developer tools are installed, the `/usr/bin/python3` stub will run the actual python3 binary, but a clean install will just have the stub.

The Python 2 binaries (`/usr/bin/python` `/usr/bin/python2`) are still present on a default installation, but they are deprecated and the warning message says they will be removed in future versions.

Comment: These stub scripts and binaries always make me smile. So much nicer than dumping a text saying to go install and authenticate for changing up a toolset.

Comment: Conversely, I find it horrifying that a thing called `/usr/bin/python3` actually puts out an xcode console message then pops up a dialog box prompting to install something. That is _not_ what `/usr/bin/python3` is supposed to do.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica What *is* it supposed to do when it's not actually installed? This seems like a descendant of what Apple did when they started removing Java from the standard installation.

Comment: @Barmar If `/usr/bin/python3` is not installed, then attempts to execute it should be met with the standard "file not found" response, whatever that is on your platform. There should simply be no file there at that path, in my opinion.

Comment: Horrifying @LightnessRaceswithMonica - that seems a bit over the top.  Wouldn’t any program or tool or person that runs that path surely understand the goal of a stub in intentionally installing a new and very incompatible version of a language? I get having a strong opinion on this, though - no argument there from me.

Comment: @bmike From a developer point of view, it makes it more difficult to check if python3 is installed.

Comment: @bmike _"Wouldn't any [..] tool [..] that runs that path surely understand the goal of a stub"_ Nope. A tool executing `/usr/bin/python3` expects Python 3, nothing else. This is pretty fundamental computer stuff!

Comment: How does the effect things if you want to install the Anaconda distribution of python 3.7?  Or does it?

Comment: @jmh Shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 13):

Yes - that file is part of the system image and ships on every Mac.

It is a stub app that calls `xcode-select --install` which installs all command line developer tools, which includes python3 binary in the same location as the stub binary that installs with the core OS.

When fully installed, version 3.7.3 is what Catalina installs from this stub. Keep in mind python 2.7.16 is the default `python` if you don’t call `python3` up until macOS 12.3 when python binary (which was v2) was removed entirely and `python3` was bumped to 3.8.9.

```
    ~ % /usr/bin/python3 --version
    Python 3.7.3

     ~ % sw_vers
    ProductName:    Mac OS X
    ProductVersion: 12.3
    BuildVersion:   21E230
```

Catalina:

```
    ~ % /usr/bin/python3 --version
    Python 3.7.3

    ~ % /usr/bin/python --version
    Python 2.7.16

     ~ % sw_vers
    ProductName:    Mac OS X
    ProductVersion: 10.15.5
    BuildVersion:   19F101
```